# Add Zero to the left in a field and concatenate Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

i have a table in my table like this

```
time           ID         d    h    m     names
00:08:04        M23456     1   12    0     Jhon
6 15:31:18      M23678     0    6    0     Robert
00:02:11        M1234      4    2    0     Smith
4 14:35:03      M46612     10   5    0     Roger
 03:45:05       M34562    null  null null   David
```

so, i trying to create a query what concatenate  the fields 'd'(day),'h'(hours) and 'm' (minutes) and transform in the same format of time adding the zero to the left if is <  10 and a space in the field 'd' for the days,

is something like

```
time            ID         d    h    m     names  newfield
00:08:04        M23456     1   12    0     Jhon    1 12:00:00
6 15:31:18      M23678     0    6    0     Robert  0 06:00:00
00:02:11        M1234      4    2    0     Smith   4 02:00:00
4 14:35:03      M46612     10   5    0     Roger  10 05:00:00
```

any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is using `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(d, '99') || ' ' || to_char(h, '00') || ':'  || to_char(m, '00') || ':00'
```

Comment: thanks Gordon thats work find, just a lil question, if i need add or delete spaces in te format  like this 0  00: 00:00  to 0 00:00:00 is in the  concatenate (||)?

Comment: If you don't want the spaces, you don't need to use trim(), just set the format to `to_char(h,'fm00')`.